# How can I retrieve via Facebook graph, the people who liked a URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a URL, for example: www.example.com
And I want to see who are the people that liked that URL, How can I retrieve that data via Facebook's Graph API?
(Currently I can Only get the liked count, but that's it)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/ Facebook documentation isn't very good on this.

Comment: Thanks, but it only returns the amount of shares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to return such a list. You can only get the insights (e.g. demographics) and counts, but not the individual user IDs.